# Merge data frames by approximate column values

Tags: r

I've got two data frames containing timeseries (with time coded as numeric, rather than time objects; and time is unsorted). I'd like to normalize a response variable in one data frame to a response variable in another data frame. The problem is that the timepoints in the two data frames aren't quite equivalent. So, I'll need to merge the two data frames by the approximate match of the two time columns.

The data look like this:

```
df1 <- structure(list(t1 = c(3, 1, 2, 4), y1 = c(9, 1, 4, 16)), .Names = c("t1", "y1"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
df2 <- structure(list(t2 = c(0.9, 4.1), y2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("t2", "y2"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

The result should look like this:

```
t1  y1    y2
 1   1    a
 4  16    b
```

Seems like `approx` or `approxfun` would be useful, but I can't quite see how to do it.

Comment: This may work for your example, but not for your problem - but you could always `round()` both before merging. Although, this can get really tricky if your measurements (a,b) are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this easily with `na.approx` from zoo:

```
library(zoo)
Data <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="t1", by.y="t2", all=TRUE)
Data$y1 <- na.approx(Data$y1, na.rm=FALSE, rule=2)
na.omit(Data)
#    t1 y1 y2
# 1 0.9  1  a
# 6 4.1 16  b
```

You could do this with `approx` too:

```
Data <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="t1", by.y="t2", all=TRUE)
y1.na <- is.na(Data$y1)
Data$y1[y1.na] <- (approx(Data$y1, rule=2, n=NROW(Data))$y)[y1.na]
```

Answer (score 1):

@JoshuaUlrich provided a nice way to do this if you want the final result to include everything from `df2` and you don't care if the `t1` column has the values from `t2`.

However, if you wanted to avoid these things and continue in the vein suggested by @BrandonBertelsen, you might define custom `round` function and then use that on the merge column of the second `data.frame`. For example:

```
# define a more precise rounding function that meets your needs.
# e.g., this one rounds values in x to their nearest multiple of h
gen.round <- function(x, h) {
    ifelse(x %% h > (h/2), h + h * (x %/% h), -(h + h * (-x %/% h)))
}

# make a new merge function that uses gen.round to round the merge column 
# in the second data.frame
merge.approx <- function(x, y, by.x, by.y, h, ...) {
    y <- within(y, assign(by.y, gen.round(get(by.y), h)))
    merge(x, y, by.x=by.x, by.y=by.y, ...)
}

merge.approx(df1, df2, by.x='t1', by.y='t2', h =.5)

  t1 y1 y2
1  1  1  a
2  4 16  b
```

Comment: Trouble is (per @Brandon Bertilsen's guess) my real time values are not necessarily integers. I like this approach, but I'm trying to figure out if it can be modified to 'round' the values of the t2 column to the non-integer values of the t1 column. That would make more intuitive sense to me.

Comment: Yes, it can. The `gen.round` function defined here rounds to the nearest multiple of `h`, where `h` can be anything, e.g., `gen.round(1.36, .5)` will give you `1.5`.